# How to Proceed a Conversation in Facebook Chatbot

Tags: python, facebook, chatbot

I'm trying to build a facebook chatbot that is able to proceed a conversation.

For example...

```
A: How's the weather?
B: Where?
A: Seoul.
B: It's cold and windy.
```

When A asks about the weather, then function Weather() is initiated. But then, since information is insufficient, the chatbot asks a question. How am I able to track this so that when A answers with additional information, I know that this is connected to the Weather() function.

Shoud I track the message logs to do this? It seems inefficient, though.

Thank you.

p.s. built with python 2.7.1

Comment: Well you will have to "track" the message history somehow - and that means storing it somewhere in the first place. Could be a session, could be a database, ... your choice.

Comment: Thanks :) I actually created a python dictionary and saved it as a txt file. Whenever the bot gets a message, it first checks this txt file and check whether the content of the dictionary is empty or not. Checking the message logs seem to be much simpler... but then I have to do the NLP thing every time I check the message. Former seemed efficient. Still, both seemed somehow inefficient... I just hoped that there are some alternative methods... thank you :)